# Get and SET Database Server Connection Variable with JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

When i open a JDBC connection to a MySQL database i want to set some database server variable, so for example every time that a connection is established i want to set the variable sqlmode with this value :

```
SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,PIPES_AS_CONCAT';
```

for enabling pipe string concatenation ...

I have to send this parameter in a query statement or can i set this parameter directly on the JDBC Connection ? Is there a property on the JDBC connection that allow set this variable ?

What is the best way to set or retrieve database server variable with a JDBC Connection ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Have you tried adding it into the getConnection call?

```
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw&sessionVariables=sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,PIPES_AS_CONCAT'";
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
```

Regards

Comment: To URL i want to add below SQL mode. Could you please help me how my url will look like.    SET @@SQL_MODE = CONCAT(@@SQL_MODE, ',PAD_CHAR_TO_FULL_LENGTH');

Comment: I had to use the %3D in the value of the sessionVariables to make it work. But this really helped me, thanks @Gigab0rt.