# setting strict mode off via url parameter in mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

unfortunately I'm not able to change this config on the server, so I have to set it off per connection. Looking into the docs I've encountered an url parameter called "connectionAttributes" but i cant get it to work.

here is the url
`my.host:3306/mydb?connectionAttributes=sql-mode:""`

Comment: From reading the documentation, `connectionAttributes` seems to be for user-defined key/value pairs, not for the purpose you have in mind

Comment: http://mysqlblog.fivefarmers.com/2013/03/26/connection-attributes-in-mysql-5-6/

if I `SELECT * FROM performance_schema.session_connect_attrs` I can see the "sql_mode" in the result set

Comment: And where do you get from that it can be used to set things like sql-mode, if anything it supports my supposition that it is for user-defined key/value pairs.

Comment: any suggestions on how to do it?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298551/get-and-set-database-server-connection-variable-with-jdbc. I have not tried it though.